# Java to c# conversion--Need help in converting the runnable method of java to c#

Tags: java, c#

I am building up a android project in Xamarin-visual studio. The runnable code of Java below is returning errors in c#.. the '}' for the runnable method are mismatching/misplacing when I add "void run()" inside the new Runnable

```
private Runnable DoImageProcessing =
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                bProcessing = true;
                getPoints();
                bProcessing = false;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Your question has nothing specifically to do with Xamarin and is going to get closed as off topic. You should reword your question and maybe consider sharing your Java code, and simply asking what the equivalent C# is. Though, even that is borderline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact translation looks like this:

```
private Action DoImageProcessing = () =>
{
    bProcessing = true;
    GetPoints();
    bProcessing = false;
}
```

But since you commented that you get a the error

> ERROR: A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property `CameraPreview.bProcessing'

It means you cannot reference the `bProcessing` variable inline like this because it is out of scope during object instantiation, you need to move the call to the class constructor.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private bool bProcessing;
    private Action DoImageProcessing; // bProcessing is out of scope here

    public SomeClass()
    {
        DoImageProcessing = () =>
        {
            bProcessing = true; // bProcessing is now in scope
            GetPoints();
            bProcessing = false;
        } 
    }

    private void GetPoints()
    {
        // implementation of GetPoints()...
    }
}
```

And then wherever the application would normally call `DoImageProcessing.run()`, you would need to call `DoImageProcessing()` (that is, add parenthesis to the `Action` variable name to execute it).

Comment: similarly I have faced one more problem while converting. private final int NONE = -1, TOUCH_TOP_FIRST = 0, TOUCH_TOP_SECOND = 1, TOUCH_BOT_THIRD = 2, TOUCH_BOT_FOURTH = 3; int currentTouch = NONE; these declaration has error in c# at int currentTouch = NONE; error: A field initialiser cannot reference non-static field,method or property CameraPreview.NONE;

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question and provide a more complete code example. Also, you can easily find some of this out by searching on Google, for example "Java final equivalent c#".

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with Java but it appears you're attempting to create a function delegate. Void returns are called Action

Try this:

```
public class ImageProcessor
{
    bool bProcessing;
    private void getPoints() { }

    public Action DoImageProcessing;

    public ImageProcessor()
    {
        DoImageProcessing = () =>
        {
            bProcessing = true;
            getPoints();
            bProcessing = false;
        };
    }
 }
```

Comment: In Java, this is actually an anonymous class that subclasses the `Runnable` interface and implements the `run()` method. That said, this is the correct way to translate it to .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @NightOwl888

Comment: i implemented it but ther is an error  ERROR: A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property `CameraPreview.bProcessing'

@NightOwl888 , @BrerrAllen

Comment: Set it in the constructor instead of the declaration then. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @viswachikkala answer is now updated to resolve that issue.

Comment: similarly I have faced  one more problem while converting.

`private final int NONE = -1, TOUCH_TOP_FIRST = 0, TOUCH_TOP_SECOND = 1, TOUCH_BOT_THIRD = 2, TOUCH_BOT_FOURTH = 3;
    int currentTouch = NONE; `


these declaration has error in c# at `int currentTouch = NONE;`

`error: A field initialiser cannot reference non-static field,method or property CameraPreview.NONE;`

Comment: static int NONE = 0;